# Find the number of duplicates in two or more arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to compare and find how many duplicates are there in two arrays.

```
const array1 = [a, b, c, d, e]
const array2 = [b, f, c, z, y]

let identical = 0

for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i] === array2[i]) {
          identical++
        }
      }

console.log(identical)
// returns 2
```

I did this but I want to use a shorter syntax (ES6 syntax)

Comment: What about duplicates in array1 or array2. For example, if array1 had 2 `b`'s: `[a, b, b, c, d]`; Would `b` also be considered a duplicate?

Comment: That's a good question. Yes that would still be considered duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reduce` can count up the number of matches pretty concisely:

```
const identical = array1.reduce(
  // on each iteration, return the prior accumulator value
  // (matches found so far)
  // plus one, if the current iteration is a match, otherwise plus zero
  (a, num, i) => a + (num === array2[i]),
  0 // initial value
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count only same items per index, you can use [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as follows:

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const array2 = ['b', 'f', 'c', 'z', 'y'];

const identical = array1.reduce((acc, item, index) => 
  array2[index]===item ? acc+1 : acc
, 0);

console.log(identical);
```

Answer (score 0):

`reduce()` is the fit for purpose method, but you can also achieve this by using [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and accessing the `length` of the returned array of identical elements.

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const array2 = ['b', 'f', 'c', 'z', 'y'];

let identical = array1.filter((e, i) => e === array2[i]).length;

console.log(identical)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are also trying to count duplicates in the original arrays, you can use a Set

```js
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const array2 = ['b', 'f', 'c', 'z', 'y'];
const combined = [...array1, ...array2];
const duplicatesCount = combined.length - new Set(combined).size;

console.log(duplicatesCount);
```